# Background image not working at all

Tags: css, background

I have been researching for a while to how to get my background image to work on different screen resolutions. After many failed attempts I noticed I can't even get a normal css background in. It's not the file, I have tried different formats.
Code for the different screen resolutions:

```css
html { 
  background: url('background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -o-background-size: contain;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

The code the normal background:

```css
body {
    background-image: url('Background.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is strange. Did you check that the path to your image is correct? For example if the image is inside an "example" folder, the path should be "example/myImage.png".

As for a responsive background, I believe you are on the right track, although a simple `background-size: 100%;` would have been enough. Check this Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/a0mvnj63/

Also try using an external image, like in my example, just in case.

Comment: Or you can use `center/cover` to fill the background image over the full background: https://jsfiddle.net/C0dekid/a0mvnj63/1/ This will fill out the background and will shrink on devices with different screen resolutions.

Comment: @C0dekid Indeed. It is more elegant this way

Answer (score 1):

Try to use your code like this `background-image:url('../background.jpg');` with `height: 100vh;`

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(http://static.tumblr.com/295a1562899724d920b2b65ba33ffb76/vouqyzj/f2Dna5qb8/tumblr_static_197ahk99f1z44ogskg4gw4c80.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h1>Hello Universe</h1> 

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

only background elements does not give height and width to any div or html.

try giving some height and width to your code. just like

```
html { background: url('background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; height:500px; width:500px; }
```

or just put some data on body so you get auto height width according to contain and get image in background.